# DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory and Concurrent Connections not shutting down

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, spring-messaging

I am using Spring 4.x's DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory in order to connect to an ActiveMQ Queue, process the messages from that queue using a @JmsListener and then push the message to a topic on the same ActiveMQ broker.

I am using a single Caching Connection Factory for both the consumer/listener and the producer, and I set the cache consumer to be false, so that I can cache the producer, but not the consumer. I also set the concurrency to be 1-3, which I expect will have a minimum of 1 consumer in the queue on application startup, and as the messages ramp up, then the number of consumers would reach 3. However, as the number of messages dwindle, I was expecting that the number of consumers would go back down to 1 as well. However, if I take a look at the threads (defaultmessagelistenercontainer-2/3), they are in a waiting state, and they do not shut down. Is it not the expected behaviour that when the load subsides, that the number of consumers would be expected to shut down as well? Please see my configurations below, and let me know if this behaviour is not out of the box, and if I need to add something to get this working as I laid out above.

**ApplicationContext.java**

```
    @Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws Throwable {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(environment.getProperty("jms.connections.concurrent"));
    factory.setSessionTransacted(environment.getProperty("jms.connections.transacted", Boolean.class));
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
    RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
    redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(environment.getProperty("jms.redelivery.initial-delay", Long.class));
    redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(environment.getProperty("jms.redelivery.delay", Long.class));
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(environment.getProperty("jms.redelivery.maximum", Integer.class));
    redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(environment.getProperty("jms.redelivery.use-exponential-back-off", Boolean.class));
    redeliveryPolicy.setBackOffMultiplier(environment.getProperty("jms.redelivery.back-off-multiplier", Double.class));

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQ = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(environment.getProperty("jms.queue.username"), environment.getProperty("jms.queue.password"), environment.getProperty("jms.broker.endpoint"));
    activeMQ.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
    activeMQ.setPrefetchPolicy(prefetchPolicy());

    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(activeMQ);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheConsumers(environment.getProperty("jms.connections.cache.consumers", Boolean.class));
    cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(environment.getProperty("jms.cache.size", Integer.class));
    return cachingConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate(){
    ActiveMQTopic activeMQ = new ActiveMQTopic(environment.getProperty("jms.queue.out"));

    JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate = new JmsMessagingTemplate(connectionFactory());
    jmsMessagingTemplate.setDefaultDestination(activeMQ);

    return jmsMessagingTemplate;
}
```

**application.properties**

```
jms.connections.concurrent=1-3
jms.connections.prefetch=1000
jms.connections.transacted=true
jms.connections.cache.consumers=false
jms.redelivery.initial-delay=1000
jms.redelivery.delay=1000
jms.redelivery.maximum=5
jms.redelivery.use-exponential-back-off=true
jms.redelivery.back-off-multiplier=2
jms.cache.size=3
jms.queue.in=in.queue
jms.queue.out=out.queue
jms.broker.endpoint=failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with setting `maxMessagesPerTask > 0`

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws Throwable {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setMaxMessagesPerTask(1);
    factory.setConcurrency(environment.getProperty("jms.connections.concurrent"));
    factory.setSessionTransacted(environment.getProperty("jms.connections.transacted", Boolean.class));
    return factory;
}
```

you can refer to the doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setMaxMessagesPerTask-int-

`jms.connections.prefetch=1000` means that if you have 1000 messages waiting on the Q you will have only 1 thread started to treat these 1000 messages.

for example `jms.connections.prefetch=1` means the messages will be dispatched equally to all available threads but with this it is better to set `maxMessagesPerTask < 0` because Long-lived tasks avoid frequent thread context switches.
http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

Comment: Thanks! I tried this out and it worked! However, when I was profiling, I noticed that the dmlc container thread was constantly being recreated, assuming based on the receive attempts and the value of max messages per task. This is just an observation, can anyone comment on that?

Comment: Yes I gave you an example with 1 max messages per task but 1 is too low as said in the documentation link I provided and each thread will die after 1 attempt. You Need to increase max messagespertask to 10 for example to permits 10 attempts and increase IdleTaskExecutionLimit to permits reusing the thread when max attempts reached . It is well explained at the doc   http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setIdleTaskExecutionLimit-int-